# jQuery Text Editor (JQTE)

Tags: javascript, jquery, asp.net-mvc-4, jquery-ui, jquery-plugins

I recently incorporated the jQuery Text Editor plugin ([here](http://jqueryte.com/demos)), in my development of an MVC project.

It was straightforward to add the plugin. However when executing my View the text editor renders as follow:

[image]

This is the code I'm using in my View:

JS references (omit the greater than and less than characters due to it's not rendered in the question):

```html
<script src="~/Scripts/jquery-1.11.1.min.js">
<script src="~/Plugins/jQuery-TE/jquery-te-1.4.0.min.js">
<link href="~/Plugins/jQuery-TE/jquery-te-1.4.0.css" rel="stylesheet">
```

HTML:

```html
<div class="row">
    <div class="col-md-9">
        <div class="panel panel-primary">
            <div class="panel-heading">
                Executive Summary
            </div>
            <div class="panel-body">
                <form role="form">
                    <div class="form-group">
                        <textarea name="textarea" class="jqte-test" placeholder="Enter some text">                     
                        </textarea>
                    </div>
                </form>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>  
</div>
```

Script for the JQTE:

```
$('.jqte-test').jqte();

// settings of status
var jqteStatus = true;
$(".status").click(function () {
    jqteStatus = jqteStatus ? false : true;
    $('.jqte-test').jqte({ "status": jqteStatus })
});
```

Comment: seems you use bootstrap, maybe there are some conflicts from `jQuery Text Editor` and bootstrap native CSS...

Comment: Hi Frogmouth. You right. I just commented out the part where the boostrap styles area loaded in the text editor now renders OK. However, the rest of the page not. I'll try to figure out what is the css style that is causing troubles. thanks

Comment: hi is this plugin supports emojis ? @Frogmouth

Comment: I really don't know. I'm so sorry @FaizalMunna.

Comment: @Frogmouth hi I like to disscuss with you something is it possible to get your email thanks

Answer (score 1):

I change the CSS rule

```
.jqte_tool.jqte_tool_1 .jqte_tool_label {
position:relative;
display:block;
padding:3px;
width:70px;
height:16px; /* change it to 20px; */
overflow:hidden; }
```

That's how it worked for me.

Answer (score 1):

Maybe for someone else:

```
.jqte_tool.jqte_tool_1 .jqte_tool_label {
    position:relative;
    display:block;
    padding:3px;
    width:70px;
    height:21px; /*change*/
    overflow:hidden;
}
.jqte_tool_label{
    padding-top: 1px !important; /*add*/
    height: 25px !important; /*add*/
}
```

works for me!

Answer (score 0):

```
.tab_point_decr, .tab_point_decr img, .tab_point_decr div {
    overflow: visible !important; /*change*/
}
.jqte_toolbar {
    overflow: auto !important;
    padding: 3px 4px;
    background: #EEE;
    border-bottom: #BBB 1px solid;
    position: inherit;
    overflow: visible !important; /*add*/
    height: 35px; /*add*/
}
.jqte_fontsizes { 
    height:auto; /*change*/
}
.jqte_cpalette {
    z-index:20; /*add*/
}
```

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! Thank you for this code snippet, which might provide some limited, immediate help.  A proper explanation [would greatly improve](//meta.stackexchange.com/q/114762) its long-term value by showing *why* this is a good solution to the problem, and would make it more useful to future readers with other, similar questions.  Please [edit] your answer to add some explanation, including the assumptions you've made.